# Using bottle.py and blobstore GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, bottle

I recently started using bottle and GAE blobstore and while I can upload the files to the blobstore I cannot seem to find a way to download them from the store.

I followed the examples from the documentation but was only successful on the uploading part. I cannot integrate the example in my app since I'm using a different framework from webapp/2.

How would I go about creating an upload handler and download handler so that I can get the key of the uploaded blob and store it in my data model and use it later in the download handler?

I tried using the `BlobInfo.all()` to create a query the blobstore but I'm not able to get the key name field value of the entity.

This is my first interaction with the blobstore so I wouldn't mind advice on a better approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For serving a blob I would recommend you to look at the [source code of the BlobstoreDownloadHandler](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/blobstore_handlers.py&l=216). It should be easy to port it to bottle, since there's nothing very specific about the framework.

Here is an example on how to use `BlobInfo.all()`:

```
for info in blobstore.BlobInfo.all():
  self.response.out.write('Name:%s Key: %s Size:%s Creation:%s ContentType:%s<br>' % (info.filename, info.key(), info.size, info.creation, info.content_type))
```

Answer (score 0):

for downloads you only really need to generate a response that includes the header "X-AppEngine-BlobKey:[your blob_key]" along with everything else you need like a Content-Disposition header if desired. or if it's an image you should probably just use the high performance image serving api, generate a url and redirect to it.... done

for uploads, besides writing a handler for appengine to call once the upload is safely in blobstore (that's in the docs)

You need a way to find the blob info in the incoming request. I have no idea what the request looks like in bottle. The Blobstoreuploadhandler has a get_uploads method and there's really no reason it needs to be an instance method as far as I can tell. So here's an example generic implementation of it that expects a webob request. For bottle you would need to write something similar that is compatible with bottles request object.

```
def get_uploads(request, field_name=None):
    """Get uploads for this request.
    Args:
      field_name: Only select uploads that were sent as a specific field.
      populate_post: Add the non blob fields to request.POST
    Returns:
      A list of BlobInfo records corresponding to each upload.
      Empty list if there are no blob-info records for field_name.

    stolen from the SDK since they only provide a way to get to this
    crap through their crappy webapp framework
    """
    if not getattr(request, "__uploads", None):
        request.__uploads = {}
        for key, value in request.params.items():
            if isinstance(value, cgi.FieldStorage):
                if 'blob-key' in value.type_options:
                    request.__uploads.setdefault(key, []).append(
                        blobstore.parse_blob_info(value))

    if field_name:
        try:
            return list(request.__uploads[field_name])
        except KeyError:
            return []
    else:
        results = []
        for uploads in request.__uploads.itervalues():
            results += uploads
        return results
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this answer in future, to do this you need bottle (d'oh!) and defnull's [multipart](https://github.com/defnull/multipart) module.

Since creating upload URLs is generally simple enough and as per GAE docs, I'll just cover the upload handler.

```
from bottle import request
from multipart import parse_options_header
from google.appengine.ext.blobstore import BlobInfo

def get_blob_info(field_name):
    try:
        field = request.files[field_name]
    except KeyError:
        # Maybe form isn't multipart or file wasn't uploaded, or some such error
        return None
    blob_data = parse_options_header(field.content_type)[1]
    try:
        return BlobInfo.get(blob_data['blob-key'])
    except KeyError:
        # Malformed request? Wrong field name?
        return None
```

Sorry if there are any errors in the code, it's off the top of my head.